# Enable Checkstyle annotation processing for Jenkins builds

Tags: jenkins, gradle, annotations

Im trying to enable the annotations in our jenkins but I don't know how to do so. Instead of using comments to disable certain rules while building on jenkins I'd like to use the annotations in the code. 
Im using gradle and custom rules via an xml.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed it myself. I read the documentation about the Suppressionfilters and according to it I added the module "SuppressWarningsHolder" and the module "SuppressWarningsFilter" and it now works both in the idea and on jenkins.